# Copy Database wizard deletes user from source?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm attempting to make a copy of a live database at a client site so the client can have a test database. (There is one already, but it's very out-of-date.) I'm using SSMS 2005's Copy Database wizard and choosing the option (SQL Management Object method) that doesn't require detaching the source database.

The copy fails, but that's not my problem. I'll sort that out, using the log created. However, I've now tried this twice, and both times, afterward, a user has been deleted from the list for the source database. Specifically, it's the only user listed for this database that isn't a standard built-in user.

I've restored the user with the appropriate rights, but this seems really bizarre to me. Any ideas on why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Tamar

Comment: I just tested this against one of the existing test databases (that is, trying to copy that one), and saw the same behavior. The same user disappeared. It seemed to happen very late in the game. I refreshed the user list several times while the task was running and the user was still there, but after the task failed, the user was gone.

Comment: And now, I tried against a different database and don't see the behavior. Seems like it's related to that particular database. The test database I tried was a test copy (albeit outdated) of the same one where I originally saw the problem.

Comment: It occurred to me to try using the other copying option (detach and attach) against the test database. That one succeeds and doesn't delete the one user. Guess I have the right approach for doing what I need to, but I'd still like to know why this happened.

Comment: I've just had this happen to me. Extremely frustrating. I'd love to get to the bottom of it but can't find out any more info about it.